# What are the modifications on this Kossel?

Tags: kossel, ruggedised-printer

*(This question is a kind of self-answer. I know who built this printer, he explained the modifications, and I thought it might be interesting for others too. I've asked him to answer this question, to keep this information on Stack Exchange. I realize this question in its current form may be "Too Broad", feel free to edit to make it more specific).*

---

I saw this Kossel Mini printer, and noted that it has some modifications. I'm told this is to make it easier to transport, and would like to know how these modifications make it more robust and more transportable.

[image: Kossel Mini printer]

Comment: I am voting to close this question as "unclear what you're asking" because it is impossible for somebody (who doesn't just happen to be the particular builder of this printer) to tell what modifications are on there from just that single picture. I think this question is also too broad (it would be better to ask a question about a specific modification like what kind of extruder is on there).

Comment: This technically could be placed in Meta as it does bring up a good point of where questions like this have a place (if at all) in SE

Comment: @tbm0115 Some of the entertainment sites (e.g. anime.SE) have identification requests. I think this question is a variant of these. They have rules about id requests - we could discuss if we need such rules here as well.

Comment: On SE.Robotics I have seen *some* questions that are of the type "Please identify this robot arm/grabber/etc.". Cool Kossel BTW! :-)

Answer (score 2):

Cool you placed my Kossel Mini on Stackexchange!
What I have modified to the standard kit:

- Retractable probe using RC Marlin (Rich Cattels Marlin with auto bed probe functionality). Never have to adjust endstops after it is once setup.
  All can be done in firmware.
- Made a transport case, in the picture the cover is missing which is a triangular case which fits over the printer.
  You can clip it on and the carry it with the handle on top.
  I just throw it in the car and bring it to the Hackerspace and Hackerevents/Makerfaires and when I feel to it, I can do an auto-probe to align it again (which is hardly needed BTW)
- Another mod is the Vaeder extruder, which is really cool in the way it uses a GT2 timing belt to drive the filament. It uses a round wheel and it drives the filament over 1/4 of the diameter of the wheel, so there is a 3 to 4 cm area where the belt drives the filament.

Advantages:

1. Lots of retracts don't "eat" into the filament causing feed issues
2. Doesn't flatten the filament. Keeps it nice and round.

Disadvantages (at this moment):

1. Not possible/ very hard to do filament swaps on the fly (to experiment with multicolor prints).
2. First time assembly can be a head ache, once you have it assembled it really works and is easy going.

And last but not least. I made a foldable Roll holder.

It is mounted on top by two M8 screws with knobs. When I am done I undo these two screws, fold in the roll holder and it is then mounted to the side of the flight case. This way I can transport printer and roll holder carrying it only using 1 hand. So I use the other hand carrying the bag with accessories like rolls of filament, 3D spray, tweezers etc.

Maybe this info helps other people new to 3D printing improve their printers, or enables them to bring printers more easily to meets and events to inspire others to build more Delta printers. As it's just mesmerizing to see them print. I love watching the print come to reality because it such beautiful piece of engineering!

Comment: Thanks for answering the question! I expect that people may edit this answer a bit; Stack Exchange tries to keep "fluff" to a minimum and focus on the technology itself. (BTW if people make edits that you disagree with, you can roll them back). You may want to edit it yourself, to show/explain _how_ some of the modifications were made. The site is all about creating content that is directly useful. And I believe the things you explained me earlier, are directly useful for people with Kossels or other delta printers.

Comment: Do you have an answer for this [How long are the carbon fibre rods for a Travelling Kossel?](https://3dprinting.stackexchange.com/questions/4012/how-long-are-the-carbon-fibre-rods-for-a-travelling-kossel)